# CSS not working in IE and Firefox

Tags: html, css

http://bit.ly/WTkIfS -- The website is not working in IE and Firefox for some reason can anyone help figure why? I've tried moving all the css to the file base.css, using the same header as the original theme and nothings worked. Why is the css not showing in these specific browsers?

Comment: What's not working?  What is it supposed to look likE?  What CSS in question is not working?  What element in particular can you point us to as a reference to something not working?  This is too vague.

Comment: Oh, come now Eli, you want to take all the mystery out of it when we could spend days trying to figure out what's not working?

Comment: Not sure that is why I'm asking you to look at the site in different browsers to see if there is something I am missing

Comment: I think you're missing the point. We're not all going to go look at it in multiple browsers to figure out what it's supposed to look like vs. what it does look like and debug all your CSS issues for you. Please go read the FAQ and then post a more approriate question.

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot of your local version please

Comment: The link to the site is available - http://bit.ly/WTkIfS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some css code in Firefox or chrome require -moz- and -wekkit-

[Here's some examples](http://www.w3schools.com/css3/css3_transitions.asp)

Comment: yes but if you look at the site in chrome and everything with css3 has -moz- and -o- for those browsers

Comment: maybe try to separate all the css links on top and all javascript links at bottom